# Limit for system of two recursive sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

I have two sequences: $u_{n+1} = \cfrac{2u_n+v_n}{3}$ and $v_{n+1} = \cfrac{u_n+3v_n}{4}$. I want to show, first, that they converge to the same limit. And then, calculate that limit (which I know is $\frac{46}{7}$.

I tried calculating by assuming $\lim u_n = \lim u_{n+1} = L = \lim v_n = \lim v_{n+1}$. And I get:

$$L = \lim u_n = \cfrac{2\lim u_n + \lim v_n}{3} = \cfrac{3L}{3}$$. But this doesn't get me anywhere.

Also tried solving the system of equations $\cfrac{2a+b}{3} = L, \cfrac{a+3b}{4} = L$ but, I mean, since the limit for $u_n$ is the same for $u_{n+1}$ it also doesn't make sense because $L = a = b$.

How can I get to the limit in this recursive sequence?

Comment: Do you really mean $v_n = \ldots$ or $v_{n+1} = \ldots$ instead in your second formula ?

Comment: @Abezhiko you are right, thank you!

Comment: And you need to give us the inital values $u_0$ and $v_0$, because the limit will depend on them.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

We have

$$
\left(\matrix{u_{n+1}\\ v_{n+1}}\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(\matrix{u_{n}\\ v_{n}}\right)
$$

or

$$
\Phi_{n+1}=M\Phi_n
$$

and $M = T\Lambda T^{-1}$ with $\Lambda = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{5}{12} \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -\frac{4}{3} \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

or

$$
T^{-1}\Phi_{n+1}= \Lambda T^{-1}\Phi_n
$$

so

$$
T^{-1}\Phi_{n}= \Lambda^nT^{-1} \Phi_0
$$

and $\Phi_n = T\Lambda^nT^{-1} \Phi_0$

etc.

Without linear algebra:

From

$$
u_{n+1} = \cfrac{2u_n+v_n}{3}\\
v_{n+1} = \cfrac{u_n+3v_n}{4}
$$

we have

$$
v_n = 3u_{n+1}-2u_n
$$

now substituting into the second

$$
3u_{n+2}-2u_{n+1} = \frac 14 u_n + \frac 34(3u_{n+1}-2u_n)
$$

so we arrive at

$$
3u_n-\frac{17}{4}u_{n-1}+\frac 54 u_{n-2}=0
$$

now assuming $u_n = \gamma^n$ we arrive at

$$
\left(3-\frac {17}{4}\gamma^{-1}+\frac 54\gamma^{-2}\right)\gamma^n=0
$$

thus obtaining the characteristic $\gamma$'s, etc.

Comment: But since limit of $u_{n+1}$ is the same as the limit of $u_n$, which is the same as the limit of $v_{n+1}$ which is the same as the limit of $v_n$, that system of equation gives me a nonsense result. What am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Note that $\Psi_n = T^{-1}\Phi_n$ represent two independent sequences, after diagonalization.

Comment: But how, if $\lim v_n = \lim v_{n+1}$ and $\lim u_n = \lim u_{n+1}$?

Comment: Is it possible to solve it without linear algebra?

Comment: @ludicrous  Perhaps, but linear algebra is for sure an efficient tool in the present case. To finish Cesareo's work, at the end you'll get the limit $\Phi_\infty = T\Lambda^\infty T^{-1}\Phi_0$, with $\Lambda^\infty = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Can you also solve it without matrices? I'm really not understanding that

Comment: I included a hint...

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to find $k$ and $\alpha$ such that:
$$\color{red}{u_{n+1} + k v_{n+1} = \alpha  \left(u_n + k v_n  \right)}$$
It's easy to find that there are 2 solutions:
$$(k,\alpha) =\left(-1, \frac{5}{12}\right)  \hspace{0.5cm} \text{and } (k,\alpha) = \left(\frac{4}{3}, 1\right) $$

---

With the first solution:
$$u_{n+1} - v_{n+1} = \frac{5}{12} \left(u_n - v_n  \right)\implies u_n - v_n = \left(\frac{5}{12} \right)^n\left(u_0 - v_0  \right)  \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty}0$$
then  $$\lim_{n\infty}u_n = \lim_{n\infty}v_n \tag{1}$$

With the second solution:
$$u_{n+1} + \frac{4}{3}v_{n+1} = u_n + \frac{4}{3}v_n  \implies u_n + \frac{4}{3}v_n = u_0 + \frac{4}{3}v_0  \tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$\frac{7}{3} L = u_0 + \frac{4}{3}v_0  \implies \color{red}{L = \frac{3}{7}\left(u_0 + \frac{4}{3}v_0\right)} $$

Comment: How did you get the first expression? $u_{n+1}  + kv_{n+1} = a(u_n+kv_n)$?

Comment: you have:   $$u_{n+1} + kv_{n+1} =(2/3 + k/4) u_n + (1/3 + 3/4\cdot k)v_n$$  Solve the equation $1/ k =  \frac{2/3 + k/4}{1/3 + 3/4\cdot  k}$, you obtain 2 values of $k$. And $\alpha = 2/3 + k/4 $

Comment: I almost understand your solution, I just can't figure out the reason for implication number 2. Why does the first proposition implies the second with the initial values?

The other thing I don't understand is how you get the second solution (I know the first solution is the difference between the two limits, but I don't understand how to get the second one intuitively).

Comment: @ludicrous The second comment answered your question. Indeed, by solving the quadratic solution, you obtain $k = -1$ or $k = 4/3$. With the first value of $k$, you prove the 2 sequences have the same limit. With the second value of $k$, you can compute the limit from the initial values of these 2 sequences.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why does the second value of $k$ allow me to compute with the initial values

Comment: @ludicrous just compute  $u_{n+1} + 4/3 \cdot v_{n +1} = ???$

Comment: I'm sorry, you are explaining it too advanced for me. I don't understand where that 4/3 came from. I know that $v_n - u_n$ corresponds to the difference of the two sequences, which gives $(5/12)^n$. That corresponds to the difference of the two sequences. But now I don't understand how you get the $u_{n+1} + 4/3v_{n+1}$. Wheres does that 4/3 term comes from? And why does the "$n+1 = n$" case implies the "$n = n_0$" case

Comment: @ludicrous, you follow the idea i gave, first, you compute 
$$u_{n+1} + k v_{n+1} = (2/3 + k/4) u_n + (1/3 + 3/4 k ) v_n$$
From the idea $u_{n+1} + k v_{n+1}   = \alpha (v_n + k v_n)$, we must have 
$$k/ 1  = \frac{ (1/3 + 3/4 k )}{ (2/3 + k/4) }$$
From that, you find the values of  $k$:  $k = -1$ and $\color{red}{k  = 4/3}$

Comment: Oh, now I see how the k is found! But I still don't get the implication of the (2) equation. Why does the first expression implies the second one (with the initial values)?